# SQL Logon Triggers with Domain Groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I've done a ton of googling and reading here and there on forums, etc. I cant find any answers with respect to using domain groups added to SQL and then running triggers for members of that group. BTW... I know very little about SQL.

So, this works with SQL accts:

```
USE master;
GO

GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO admintest;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER connection_trigger
ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS 'admintest'
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
IF ORIGINAL_LOGIN()= 'admintest' AND
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
            WHERE is_user_process = 1 AND
                original_login_name = 'admintest') > 2
    ROLLBACK;
END;
```

But when I add domain security groups that have been added to SQL I get this:

```
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Procedure connection_trigger, Line 7
Cannot execute as the login '[testdomain\domain admins]', because it does 
not exist or you do not have permission.
```

Both have the exact same permissions. admintest works. Yet, I get an error if I add a group.

Comment: Might be better asked in the dba.stackexchange network.  Recommend migrating...you'll reach a better audience for this type of question there.

Comment: >>>But when I add domain security groups <<< WHERE did you add these groups?

Comment: sepupic: Domain Admins is a Domain Security Group. I added it to SQL logins before I started down the trigger road. twelfth - Thanks! :0

Comment: I asked where did you add them IN YOUR CODE

Comment: Sepupic - sorry about that. I replaced admintest with '[exampledomain\domain admins]' I've tried it without the quotes and without brackets. The only place SQL gets upset (red squiggly line) is line 7 "execute as '[exampledoman\domain admins]' - The other parts have no red error underline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cannot execute as the login '[testdomain\domain admins]', because it
> does  not exist or you do not have permission.

You tried to impersonate Windows group and this is not allowed, please read the documentation: [EXECUTE AS Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql)

> **' login_name '**
>
> Specifies the statements inside the module execute in
> the context of the SQL Server login specified in login_name.
> Permissions for any objects within the module are verified against
> login_name. login_name can be specified only for DDL triggers with
> server scope or logon triggers. **login_name cannot be a group**, **role,
> certificate, key, or built-in account, such as NT
> AUTHORITY\LocalService, NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService, or NT
> AUTHORITY\LocalSystem**

However, the main problem here is not that you tried to impersonate a group, but that you don't understand WHY do you use `EXECUTE AS` clause.

When someone will execute your trigger he should be able to see ALL the sessions, not only his own session, so he shoud have `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission. That is why the trigger use `EXECUTE AS` clause with the login that has been granted this permission.
So you use **any** login that has this permission in `EXECUTE AS` clause and there is absolutely no need to execute the trigger from the name of Windows group

Comment: Sepupic - Thanks so much for taking the time to answer. I got the trigger to work with an SQL acct using the "grant server" and "execute as" clause and for "original_login and "original_login_name" I used the domain security groups. Because I'm building a box with no SQL accounts (employer direction) and all domain groups and aside from the execute as clause is there anyway to to deploy triggers with domain accounts only? If not, cool. Again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @bspencer505 Sorry I did not understand what is your problem. Can you describe please what your trigger should do?

Comment: Logon trigger will fire against every login, the only thing to consider is that original_login_name will NEVER show Win group, it will always show single win account as it is single account to log on, not the group

Comment: Limit logons to say, 5 for all users -

Comment: "Logon trigger will fire against every login, the only thing to consider is that original_login_name will NEVER show Win group, it will always show single win account as it is single account to log on, not the group –" - Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: So you want to implement another thing, not max 5 connections for the same account, but no more than 5 connections at all?

Comment: To limit overall user connections you can use server option 'user connections', not the logon trigger. Here is the link ho to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-user-connections-server-configuration-option

Comment: Yes - no more than 5. DOH 2017 not approved for use here. :( - using 2014 ent.

Comment: What is "DOH"? server options are available for ages, not only in 2017

Comment: Even if they say "SQL Server (starting with 2008)", it was even in 2000 if not in 6.5

Comment: ahhh..... Thanks, Sepupic. I have alot going on and just saw the "how to.... 2017" - I should have read further. DOH=Homer... you know and finally thanks again for all your insight. I really appreciate it.